# How to append to an existing Excel file without overwriting it using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

```
private void newsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int y;
    string[] range;
    range = new string[999];

    if ( newid.Text != null)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coach ceazar\CLIENTS", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        for (y = 1; y < xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; y++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[y][newid.Text].copy();
            range[y] = Clipboard.GetText();
        }

        xlApp.UserControl = false;
        xlWorkBook.Close(false);

        xlWorkBook =  xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coach ceazar\classes\" + classes[classnumber-1].Text+".xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        for (int w = 1; w < y; w++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[w][xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count+1]=range[w];
        }

        xlApp.UserControl = false;
        xlWorkBook.Save();
        xlApp.Visible = true; 
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("please enter the id to be enrolled!");
}
```

I am trying to copy an entire row from one Excel file to another using C#. This is my current code, but each time the code runs, it is overwriting what was already in the Excel file. It has really frustrated me - can anyone please help?

Comment: You're calling `xlWorkBook.Save();` which saves the changes back to the file.  What do you *want* to happen there?

Comment: note that i have tried many different solutions and codes, none of which seemed to help. this code was only the last on i tried after hundreds of fails!

Comment: @rory.ap i want changes to be saved but i want my new info to be appended to the excel file and not to replace what was already written

Comment: So you need to find the first unused spot and put your data in it, not just start at the top